# How to sign a file with openssl on Windows 7

Tags: windows, encryption, openssl, rsa, sign

I want to sign a file with my private key via openssl on windows but it gives me this error

```
dgst: Can only sign or verify one file.
error in dgst
```

The command that I'm using is this

```
OpenSSL> dgst -sha256 -sign C:\Users\admin\Downloads\2\private.key -out ava.sha256 ava.txt
```

A friend of mine got it working under ubuntu with those commands

```
openssl dgst -sign private.key -sha256 message.txt > message.sign
```

Comment: could you test it with `-in ava.txt`

Comment: @kelalaka Got it working, using the same command my friend did, under ubuntu. Dont know why it worked there.